# Return second max by group from data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, max

How can I return the second max by group in R data table with the id column returned as well?

Reproducible example below:

```
library(data.table)
sample_dt <- data.table(
  myid=c("A","B","B","A","B","B","C","C","A","A"),
  mycol1 =c(101,-108,140,140,-150,-140,-111,101,150,140)
)

#desired output 
desired_dt <- data.table(
  myid=c("A","B","C"),
  mycol1_secondmax=c(140,-108,-111)
)
```

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution:

```
sample_dt[order(-mycol1),.SD[2],by=myid]
     myid mycol1
   <char>  <num>
1:      A    140
2:      B   -108
3:      C   -111
```

EDIT: comparison with `frank` and others

```
sample_dt <- data.table(
  myid=sample(LETTERS,10^4,replace=T),
  mycol1 =sample(-100:100,10^4,replace=T)
)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sample_dt[order(-mycol1),.SD[2],by=myid],
  sample_dt[, .SD[frank(-mycol1, ties.method = "first") == 2L,], by = .(myid)],
  sample_dt[, .SD[order(-mycol1) == 2], myid]
  )

Unit: milliseconds
                                                                               expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
                                       sample_dt[order(-mycol1), .SD[2], by = myid] 1.450001 1.850001 3.139760 3.145701 3.899852 13.6538   100
 sample_dt[, .SD[frank(-mycol1, ties.method = "first") == 2L,      ], by = .(myid)] 6.816001 7.199701 8.289604 7.638501 8.390902 22.0289   100
                                        sample_dt[, .SD[order(-mycol1) == 2], myid] 4.503801 4.824001 5.606895 5.229701 5.872300 15.9330   100
```

Comment: Suggestion: use `sample_dt[, .SD[frank(-mycol1, ties.method = "first") == 2L,], by = .(myid)]` instead, as it uses the DT-canonical/efficient `frank` instead, reducing data-copying

Comment: @r2evans, see comparison update with more groups : `frank` isn't better in this case

Comment: ...and that difference becomes apparent already for "only" 26 groups (`LETTERS`). Try e.g. 1e6 groups; `ng = 1e6`, `n = 5`; `d = data.table(id = rep(1:ng, n), v = round(rnorm(ng * n), 2))` A bit more efficient to order data _once_, than to call `frank` for _each_ group. ;)

Comment: Don't you `order` for each group too? My belief is that `frank` is intended to be faster, esp in grouping operations, so either it's a bug or there's a sweet spot with number of rows or number of groups.

Comment: @r2evans No. Please see `?data.table` or corresponding section in the intro doc: [b) General form - in what way is a data.table enhanced?](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html): "Take `DT`, subset/reorder rows using `i`, _then_ compute `j` grouped by `by`." The "_then_" is key here.

Comment: I see. I think I looked at ThomasIsCoding's answer and unconsciously _projected_ it's use of `order(.)==2` (albeit within the `.SD` portion, different) with this one. Thanks @Henrik

Answer (score 3):

Another `data.table` option

```
> sample_dt[, .SD[order(-mycol1) == 2], myid]
   myid mycol1
1:    A    140
2:    B   -108
3:    C   -111
```

Answer (score 1):

3rd option using `setorder` and later extract, i.e. `` `[` `` as part of a helper function:

```
setorder(sample_dt, myid, -mycol1)
fun <- function(x) {
  if(length(x) == 1) x else x[2]
}
```

Result

```
sample_dt[, fun(mycol1), by = myid]
#    myid   V1
# 1:    A  140
# 2:    B -108
# 3:    C -111
```